# Why we need NDS server(not top-level DNS) even my domain is in Second-level

Tags: tcp, dns

1.I registered a domain through a registrar company, I suppose the domain is **"mydomain.com"**

2.I run `$dig +trace mydomain.com` in terminal and the terminal output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> +trace mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd

.           119951  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
....... omitted......
.           119951  IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 
;; Received 525 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) in 65 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.

;; Received 1170 bytes from 193.0.14.129#53(k.root-servers.net) in 105 ms

....... omitted......


mydomain.com.       172800  IN  NS registrar1.companydns.com.
mydomain.com.       172800  IN  NS registrar2.companydns.com.

....... omitted......


mydomain.com.       600 IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
;; Received 55 bytes from xx.xx.xx.xx#53(registrar2.companydns.com.) in 96 ms
```

I am curious about why the top-level DNS don't return

`mydomain.com.      600 IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
directly but return

`mydomain.com.      172800  IN  NS registrar2.companydns.com.`
instead, I must recur once more to get the IP of "**mydomain.com**".

My question is what's the necessary of DNS(the DNS of registrar company offered) in this occasion.

Comment: DNS is a hierarchical and decentralized naming system (mostly for performance and high-availability/resilience reasons I guess). So, answer to your question is probably the same as answer to "Why don't we rely on root servers to resolve all queries"

Comment: In the occasion I issued above, the root servers may only store the IP or domain of DNS servers who store the informations of all domains end with ".com", and every time querying domain with **.com**, it just return them.So it don't need to store the second-level domain's informations.
But the second-level DNS already store the informations about my domain "mydomain.com", why it don't just return the IP of my server directly but return a DNS server, I need to query once more to get the IP of my server. It's a waste of time.

Comment: I know it must have reasons, But what's the reason, load balancing or easy to modify the IP of my domain?I am curious.(I am not good at English, I am so sorry if my expression is obscure or grammar is wrong.)

Comment: You reasoning is pretty much correct. There are (hundreds of) millions registered .com domains, many of them with thousands of subdomains and hostnames which can change ip address very frequently. Imagine that load on .com name servers, compared to just storing a couple of NS records per domain which change very rarely and can also be safely cached for longer period of time.

Comment: lol, thank you very much for answering my question, thank you.